# What are the avaliable font sizes in texlive?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex

I'm using texlive 2010, and I'm trying to design the layout for a document in plain tex (because I need the document and also I want to learn tex). The input is the following

```
\font\fifteenrm=cmr15

\font\eighteenbf=cmbx18

\font\twelvebf=cmbx12

\hrule height1mm
\vskip 2mm

{\fifteenrm \noindent Chapter 1}
\vskip 18mm

{\eighteenbf \noindent Analysis I}
\vskip 35mm

{\twelvebf \noindent This is the title}\par

Here is some text...

\bye
```

the cmr15, cmbx18, and cmbx12 are font files that tex reads and loads but I didn't understand where are those files actually in the system. I looked in the log and found some hints. The log is the following

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (Web2C 2010) (format=pdftex 2011.2.24)  24 APR 2012 12:12
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Book.tex
(./Book.tex [1{c:/texlive/2010/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] )
 <c:/Users/Felipe/.texlive2010/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/sauter/cmbx18.6
00pk> <c:/Users/Felipe/.texlive2010/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/sauter/cmr
15.600pk><c:/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb>
<c:/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on Book.pdf (1 page, 32853 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 40 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 18 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

My question is why is tex looking in two different paths (one is c:/Users/Felipe/... and the other is c:/texlive/2010/...) and how does tex know where it has to search to find an specific font (e.g. cmbx18)?

Comment: `cmbx18` and `cmr15` aren't "standard" sizes.  the font files are bitmapped in `pk` files which were compiled from a formula provided by a custom package by john sauter, quite possibly on your own system.  the `cmbx12` and `cmr10` fonts, on the other hand, *are* "standard", and are provided in tex live in type 1 form as `.pfb` files.  the bitmapped fonts may not fare so well when output on a device other than one that has exactly 600dpi resolution.  the type 1 (outline) fonts will scale smoothly to almost any resolution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original Computer Modern Roman fonts in upright shape (`cmr`) are designed only at sizes 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12 and 17.

However the TeX Live system is able to produce on demand other sizes based on the [interpolation scripts by John Sauter](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/sauter/doc/description). So when you ask for `cmr18`, the system runs the script and the font is created (a `.tfm` file and a bitmap for the rendering on screen an on print, the `.600pk` file).

It would be probably better to ask for

```
\font\fifteenrm=cmr12 at 15pt
```

which will scale `cmr12` and you'll get a Type1 font for rendering. Similarly for `cmbx`, which is available at the maximum size of 12pt (in the original form).

Comment: How can I know what are the maximum sizes for each kind of font (roman, bold, italic, etc)?

Comment: @Felipe Look in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/`

Comment: @egreg: Can we use it to get a fractional size, say 10.5pt?

Comment: @HarishKumar With the Sauter fonts, yes, but a bitmap font will be used for rendering.